# Mysqli error while callling second function in the same file

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php

    function insertData()
    {
        include_once 'database/connection.php';

        echo "<br>============= Insert Data =================<br>";

        try{
            $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (activity_date, activity_name, activity_point) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $activity_date, $activity_name, $activity_point);

            // set parameters and execute
            $activity_date = "06-APR-2020";
            $activity_name = "Test";
            $activity_point = "5";
            $res = $stmt->execute();

            var_dump("<br>Res:- ".$res);
            print_r("<br>Result:- ".$res);

            if ($res) {
                echo "<br>Id:- ".$conn->insert_id;
                echo "<br>New records created successfully";
            }
            else{
                echo "<br>New records not inserted successfully";
            }

        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo "Exception:- ".$e;
        }
        finally{
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close(); 
        }
    }


    // insertData();

    function selectData()
    {

        include_once 'database/connection.php';

        echo "<br>============= Select Data =================<br>";
        try{
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE activity_id > ?";

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $activity_id);

            // set parameters and execute
            $activity_id = 6;
            $stmt->execute();

            if (!$stmt->errno) {
                // Handle error here
            }

            $result = $stmt->get_result(); //

            $rows = $result->num_rows;



            if ($rows > 0){
                while ($data = $result->fetch_all())
                {
                    // var_dump($data);
                    var_export($data);
                    echo "<br>";
                    print_r($data);
                }
            } 
            else{
                echo "Data Not Found";
            }


        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo "Exception:- ".$e;
        }
        finally{
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close(); 
        }
    }

    selectData();


?>
```

The insert function call correctly and data is also inserted correctly.

After inserting I am closing the connection in the finally block.

But at the same time calling selectData() function I got an error.

Undefined variable: conn and Undefined variable: stmt.

How should I reopen the connection for second function?

Comment: Let me guess. You initialize `$conn` in the `database/connection.php` file. `require_once` does what is says on the tin. It only loads the file the first time you call it

Answer (score 1):

As you use `include_once` for your database connection inside the function, this will only load the script the first time.  Also at the end of the function you close the connection...

```
$conn->close();
```

The second time it calls the function, the include is not done again and the connection is closed, so the connection is not re-made.

You should only create 1 connection for the entire script (rare exceptions may apply).  So at the start of your script use the include and then pass the connection to any function/class which need to use it.

```
include_once 'database/connection.php';

insertData($conn);
```

Add the parameter to your functions...

```
function insertData( $conn )
```

and leave the closing of the connection to the system.

One last thing, which is more my preference is to use `require_once` or `require` rather than `include_once` or `include` as they will stop the script if the file cannot be found.

Comment: Getting error:  Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\wfm\index.php on line 56

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\wfm\index.php:57 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wfm\index.php(97): selectData(Object(mysqli)) #1 {main} Next Error: Call to a member function close() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\wfm\index.php:92 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wfm\index.php(97): selectData(Object(mysqli)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wfm\index.php on line 92

Comment: Do you close the connection anywhere else?

Comment: The code remains the same. I had just passed the connection in the function and at the top outside the function I had added the require at the top of the file.

Comment: You need to remove all calls to `$conn->close(); `.